# Can't log in to format or remove Ubuntu

Tags: format

I can't log in to my Dell Laptop Inspiron 15 with Ubuntu 14.04LTS software. would any body please  tell me How to format my laptop considering fact i can't log in.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: If you format your hard drive, you will lose all data installed including:

- Files
- Programs
- Ubuntu installation.

In order to get any data that you want to restore later:

1. Create a ubuntu live usb/cd.
2. Boot from it and open a terminal.
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo su
   mkdir /mnt/mnt1
   mount /dev/xxx /mnt/mnt1
   cd /mnt/mnt1/home/username
   ```

   Then copy all the files you want to keep to a USB device or other storage media.

Then formatting the drive:

1. If you are going to reinstall ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo su
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/xxx
   ```

   Then reinstall ubuntu.
2. If you are going to install windows:

   ```
   sudo su
   mkfs.nfts /dev/xxx
   ```

   Then install windows.

Your hard drive will be formatted!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also use the live disk to access files on your computer and copy them to external media, then either reinstall Ubuntu or look for a program called "gparted" and format your drive. Warning: which ever of our answers you accept be sure to back up data first.